# Try - Except multiple except error

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
try:
    hotel.objects.get(id=id).delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Deleted')
except:
    car.objects.get(id=id).delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Deleted')
except:
    person.objects.get(id=id).delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Deleted')
except:
    messages.error(request, 'Error')
```

I'll try to delete `hotel` or `car`. It works great with this method, but I need to delete one more `model` and if I try to delete a `model` that's not here I want an `Error`. But I can only have one `except`, otherwise it gives me the following error:

> SyntaxError:default 'except' must be the last

How can I make it work?

Comment: You can nest try-excepts if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your syntax is incorrect. You can't have multiple `except` blocks in the same level each catching exception of a different code block. For the sake of correctness, it should be:

```
try:
    hotel.objects.get(id=id).delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Deleted')
except:
    try:
        car.objects.get(id=id).delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Deleted')
    except:
        try:
            person.objects.get(id=id).delete()
            messages.success(request, 'Deleted')
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'Error')
```

But this is not a good code style. If you have more models to delete, you would end up having a long code chain. What I suggest is having a list of models, then just loop on it and try to delete one by one:

```
models = [hotel, car, person]
for model in models:
    try:
        model.objects.get(id=id).delete()
        messages.success(request, 'Deleted')
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: You can have multiple `except` block but you have to specify for each except but the last one what type of error are you expecting https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: in the second code block the code above needs a `break` after the line which does a `delete()`, otherwise you do a delete on hotel *and* a delete on car *and* a delete on person which - if I understand you correctly - is not what you want to do

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu OP's intention is to use another `except` to capture the exception that the first `except` block throws. Same level `except` can only capture different exceptions from the **same** code block. But I edited my post to reflect the clarification. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sir @ShangWang worked the first code, the second one didn't work properly. Thank you

Comment: @verocoding `didn't work properly` is not helpful at all. What doesn't work?

Comment: @ShangWang I wrote this comment before you edited your answer, so now my previous comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @ShangWang The first one is great, working as expected. The second one for example if I have hotel, car and person created. I want to delete `person` but says `error`, same with `car`, but if I want to delete `hotel` works great, says `Deleted` , I tried with a `break` as @hansaplast said, but nothing

Comment: @verocoding I edited the second example, this should work now as expected, can you check?

Comment: @hansaplast Why when I want to add `except: messages.error(request, 'error') pass` got Deleted and Error as well?